# In php-mysql, How should I write the variable $row['disease_$lang2'] in while sentence?

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing the programming step by step. At last I met the php code for the result display from the sql query. 
I test the echo $sql and that works well.
and I test the rest. This is my php code as like below

```
 $sql = "SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_$lang2.disease_$lang2 
 FROM code_co  LEFT JOIN code_$lang2 ON code_$lang2.code = code_co.code
 WHERE code_co.code = '".$code."'";

 $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

 echo "<table border='1' style='background:#dddddd;border-color:green;'>";

   echo "<tr>";
  echo "<th >Code</th>";
  echo "<th >병명</th>";
  echo "<th >Disease name</th>";

  echo "</tr>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {     
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td >" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td >" .$row['disease_co']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['disease_."$lang2"']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
```

$row['code'] and $row['disease_co'] are good output. But $row['disease_."$lang2"'] is not.
How should I write that variable correctly? 
Please, help me.

Comment: try `$row['disease_'.$lang2]`

Comment: `$row['disease_'.$lang2]` or `$row["disease_$lang2"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use it**

```
 echo "<td>".$row['disease_'.$lang2]."</td>";
```

Answer (score 2):

Just concat it:

```
  echo "<td>".$row['disease_'.$lang2]."</td>";
```

or

```
  echo "<td>".$row["disease_$lang2"]."</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code:

```
$row['disease_'.$lang2]; // (.) dot concatenates variable with disease_.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, which is just a minor edit to your current code:

```
//Assuming that the variable name is $lang2

$sql = "SELECT code_co.code, code_co.disease_co, code_{$lang2}.disease_{$lang2} FROM code_co  LEFT JOIN code_{$lang2} ON code_{$lang2}.code = code_co.code WHERE code_co.code = '".$code."'";
```

**PHP** allows you to expand variables inside double-quotes using the `{}` braces